# Jquery mouseover submenu slide-out HEIGHT

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-hover

I'm a newbie; need some help! I created a left-aligned navigation menu with a slide-out submenu. I'm happy with everything except for the sub-menu's height. How can I make the entire slide-out menu (the opaque one) go to 100% height of the entire screen? Want it to look like this: http://perezweddings.com/blog/

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alh3168/hE6Sv/10/

Do I need to change something in here?:

```
div.menu ul.second li a {
  width: 150px;
  bottom: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #B2CC7F;
  color: #00293E;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 10px 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  background: #000; 
  background-color:rgba(0,180,180,0.3);
  padding-left:20px;
  font-family: Neou-Bold; 
  src: url('Neou-Bold.otf'); 
  font-size:10px;
  letter-spacing:1.6px ;
}
```

Comment: The `second` lists have absolute positioning, while their parents are relatively positioned, so if it has top/left values of 0/0 it is not at the very top left of the page, but at the very top left of its parent element. One possibility of being able to adjust the height is to take them out as child elements of the parent lists.

Comment: Do you use firebug or a similar tool? You should if you don't. I used it to find out that the way the page you linked solves this problem is by just adding an absurd amount of padding to the <ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the color is on the sub-menu anchors. We need to move that to the parent `ul.second` element, and then add CSS to make that element fixed and span from the top to the bottom.

```
div.menu ul.second {
    background-color:rgba(0,180,180,0.3);
    top:0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Once that has been done, we need to update the anchor style to set the background color of sub-menu items to transparent by default since the background color is coming from the parent element.

```
div.menu ul.second li a {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

You'll probably want to add some padding to the `div.menu ul.second` element as well and there are some other things you may want to adjust, but you can quickly add this CSS to the bottom of your fiddle to see it working.

Comment: When 'div.menu ul.second' is changed to fixed position, the list items go to the top of the screen. Is there away around this while still having the sub-menu have a height:100%?

Comment: You can add padding to the top or something along those lines.